# What problems or demands does the introduction of AIXM 5.1 solve?

Tags: aeronautical-information, aim

I just wonder what was the benefit of introducing AIXM ([Aeronautical Information Exchange Model](https://aixm.aero/)) version 5.1+?
What problems or demands does the new version (with its complex temporary model) actually solve?
It allows some more complex scenarios, but I cannot imagine any real life use cases that were not possible in AIXM 4.5.
Might be that there are some more detailed Feature/Entity attributes. But that could be done with AIXM 4.5+?

Could anybody explain the need to me?

Answer (score 6):

This version 5+ includes *temporality* at the feature level (in 4.5 it was at the message level). The model allows **feature** properties to change with time.

[image]

[Source](https://blog.solitec.com/aixm-45-vs-aixm-5-overview-part-1/).

Version 5+ supports dynamic data. A value is associated with a validity period, and it can exist multiple values associated with different periods of validity for the same property.

From [aixm.aero](https://aixm.aero/sites/default/files/imce/AIXM51/aixm_temporality_1.0.pdf):

> The purpose of the AIXM Temporality Concept is to enable the modelling and encoding of aeronautical data in relation with the time. As compared to the previous version 0.5, the version 1.0 (released with AIXM 5.1) includes some clarifications with regard to Schedules/Timesheets and some editorial corrections.

> [image]

Typical temporary changes: Closed runway, inoperative aid, frequency change, obstacles... This example of a closure for one hour of an airport demonstrates dynamic data, and the part which was not available in 4.5:

[image]

[Source](https://blog.solitec.com/aixm-45-vs-aixm-5-overview-part-1/).

As soon as the schedule of changes haves been entered in the database, it's easy to automatically prepare and schedule the corresponding NOTAMs. This is what is targeted by this upgrade of the model:

> In order to satisfy the temporal requirements of aeronautical information systems, AIXM must include an exhaustive temporality model, which enables a precise representation of the states and events of aeronautical features. In particular, this shall enable the development and the implementation of digital NOTAM.

Comment: Yes, that's very generic and that is reflected in AIXM4.5 as well. More simple - less opportunities of different (miss)interpretations. I do not see the need for the extended model. What use case could not have been addressed before.

Comment: @m.weiloa. The point is temporality is now at the feature level, and dynamic data are available. I added an example in the answer.